# RxJS: How to wait for several observables, even if one or many fail

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I was using the `zip` operator to wait for three observables and process the result simultaneously:

```
Observable
   .zip(
      this.sapService.getProductSpareParts(this.identForm.get('ident').value),
      this.mediacacheService.getMediaItemsByIdent(this.identForm.get('ident').value),
      this.mediacacheService.getMetaInfos(this.identForm.get('ident').value)
    )
    .subscribe((results: any) => {
      // do stuff
    });
```

It is possible that one or many of those three observables fail and return a 500 result. In this case, all other pending observables will be cancled.

**How can I ignore the erroneous observables, don't cancel them and wait for the remaining observables to complete, to process the results of the successfull observables?**

Comment: Add a catch to each of the 3 observables

Comment: Have you tried adding a `catch` operator to that chain? That should work

Answer (score 2):

Have a look a below solution i think this will solve your problem

```
var source = Rx.Observable.onErrorResumeNext(
     Rx.Observable.just(42),
     Rx.Observable.throw(new Error()),
     Rx.Observable.just(56),
     Rx.Observable.throw(new Error()),
     Rx.Observable.just(78)
   );

var subscription = source.subscribe(
     data => console.log(data)
   );
```

Result

// => 42

// => 56

// => 78

Comment: this is UMD  syntax, you should consider to provide  Node style syntax instead. [this operator can be find here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/onErrorResumeNext.ts), New global namespace is also : `rxjs` in umd

Answer (score 2):

As Robin suggested, use the `catchError` operator with the `pipe` operator on each of the observables:

```
Observable
  .zip(
    this.sapService.getProductSpareParts(this.identForm.get('ident').value).pipe(catchError(val => of(`I caught: ${val}`))),
    ...
  )
  .subscribe((results: any) => {
    // do stuff
  });
```

See https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/catch.html for more information.