# RxJS: How to fire 2 parallel requests, one of which is optional, with a timeout

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I have a case, where i have to fire 2 GET Requests at the same time:

1. First one of them is **mandatory**. I have to wait for response, and if some error pops up, i have an exception handling, and i also can already cancel my 2. request.
2. Second one is **optional**. In case of error, i can ignore the case. And i want to wait for max. 5 seconds "more" for this call, if it takes longer i want to cancel the request (i know i cant cancel the fired request but simply ignore the returned value/or returned error). So, if the 1. call may need 20sec. the 2. call may wait max. 25sec. If the 1. call needs just 1sec. the 2. call cannot wait more than 6 sec. etc.

How can i implement this with rxjs?

I know i can zip multiple requests, but all the examples i have seen so far had just 1 error handling block, but here i need to differentiate between two error cases.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please check below link might help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50677650/rxjs-how-to-wait-for-several-observables-even-if-one-or-many-fail/50678029#50678029

Answer (score 1):

I have more of a workaround than a solution.
Your requirement is to fire parallel requests and depending on the first requests response cancel the second.

Parallel requests can be done using `forkJoin` but all the observables resolve together,

`merge()` will also fire parallel requests but any response can come in any order. With merge() we will not be able to identify which response came from which Observable. If you have the freedom to modify the returned observable and add a flag to indicate about the Observable index Then you can achieve it with some extra flags and a code look this:

```js
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  obsOne = of('First Obs').pipe(map((res) => {
    return {
      firstObs: true,
      result: res
    }
  }))
  obsTwo = of('Second Obs').pipe(delay(6000))

  secondObsReturned = false
  timerHandle
  obsSubcription: Subscription;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.obsSubcription = merge(this.obsOne, this.obsTwo).subscribe((data) => {

      // you can add all this logic in pipe(map()) instead of handling in subscribe

      console.log(`data returned`, data)
      // some appropriate checks here
      if (typeof data === 'object' && data.hasOwnProperty('firstObs')) {
        if (!this.secondObsReturned) {
          // can use rxjs timer here
        this.timerHandle = setTimeout(() => {
          console.log('Delayed more than 5 seconds');
          this.obsSubcription.unsubscribe();
        }, 5000)
        }
      }
      else {
        // this is the second onservable (which may have come early)
        this.secondObsReturned = true;
      }
    })
  }
}
```

See an example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s6wkk2

---

**EDIT**

So, I was thinking of some way to use avoid altering the returned Observable and I came up with `CombineLatest`. The thing with combine latest is, for the first time it will wait for a value in both the Observables, after that it will emit even if any of the Observable resolve.

To use this, there is again a constraint. For example you need to know a particular value which the Observables will never return, say `false`, so if you know that the Observables will never retrurn `false` (or any default value) then you can make use of BehaviorSubjects and combineLatest. Initialize the BehaviorSubjects with the value which can never be returned.

You will need to tap the observable to add values to the subject.

```js
// give appropriate types
subjectOne = <any> new BehaviorSubject(false); // will contain value of the first observable
subjectTwo = <any> new BehaviorSubject(false); // will contain value of the second observable
takeUntilSub = new Subject(); // use this to stop the subscriptions

obsOne = of('First Obs')
  .pipe(
    tap((value) => {
      this.subjectOne.next(value);
    }),
    catchError((e) => {
      // if an Error occurs in first then you don't want to proceeed at all
      // add an error in the subjectOne, this will stop the combineLatest stream.
      this.subjectOne.error('Observable one errored')
      return throwError;(e)
    })
  )

obsTwo = of('Second Obs')
  .pipe(
    delay(6000),
    tap((value) => {
      this.subjectTwo.next(value);
    }),
    catchError((e) => {
      // if you want to continue the stream, you need to handle the error and return a success.
      // no need to populate the subject coz you don't care about this error
      return of(e)
    })
  )

secondObsReturned = false
timerHandle;

ngOnInit() {

  // calling the actual Observables here.
  merge(this.obsOne, this.obsTwo).pipe(takeUntil(this.takeUntilSub)).subscribe()

  // this will be called once for the very first time giving values as false for both of them (or the emitted initial values)
  // after that when any one of them resolves, flow will come here
  combineLatest(this.subjectOne, this.subjectTwo).pipe(takeUntil(this.takeUntilSub)).subscribe(([dataFromObsOne, dataFromObsTwo]) => {

    console.log(`data received: ${dataFromObsOne} and ${dataFromObsTwo}`)

    if (dataFromObsTwo !== false) {
      // second observable was resolved
      this.secondObsReturned = true;
      if (this.timerHandle) {
        clearTimeout(this.timerHandle);
      }
    }

    if (dataFromObsOne !== false) {
      // first observable resoved
      if (!this.secondObsReturned) {
        // if second obs hasn't already been resolved then start a timer.
        this.timerHandle = setTimeout(() => {
          console.log('Delayed more than 5 seconds');
          this.takeUntilSub.next(true);   // stop all subscriptions
        }, 5000)
      }
    }
  })
}
```

See an example here: [Code Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gegq3h?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: how is the error handling here? for example if the 2. call throws error? will the "subscribe" still be called?

Comment: @akcasoy: No error has to be handled at each Observable separately, let me update this answer, you can look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56041453/rxjs-observable-never-keeps-like-subscription/56041827#56041827

Comment: @akcasoy In the added link, the second observable is an erroring Observable while the first is delayed, even after an error you should be able to see the results of both in subscription. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wimngp?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @akcasoy See if the edited section of the answer works good for you.

Comment: thanks a lot. i will inform you if this achieves what i want. or / whether there is a simpler / better way of doing it without implementing this logic manually, with setTimeout etc.. rxJs has also a timeout which you can pipe..

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of forkJoin operator. This operator is used when you have multiple requests but have to wait for the response of the first request and then the next request can be triggered.

More Information can be found on the RxJS documentation for [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) operator.

Following is a snippet i tried to put together:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient)

this.url1 = 'Url 1';
this.url2 = 'Url 2';

public forkJoinExample(): Observable<any> {

   let data_1 = this.http.get(this.url1);
   let data_2 = this.http.get(this.url2);

return forkJoin([data1, data2]);

}
```

For adding the wait, you can make use of [defer](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-defer) operator. It should be fairly straightforward to implement defer too.

Another way to implement this can be with the following snippet:

```
   let data_1 = this.http.get(this.url1);
   let data_2 = this.http.get(this.url2);

const observableData = Rx.Observable.forkJoin([data1, data2]);

observableData.subscribe(
res => {
   // Handle response
},
(err) => {
   // Handle Error Scenario
},
() => {
   // Executes when all the requests are completed
});
```

There is another method to handle multiple error blocks, i can add those if you want me to add. You can just forkjoin individual service calls and finally subscribe to the final request and add as many response and error blocks within these individual requests.

Comment: first of all, i want to fire them at the same time. secondly by rxjs documentation of forkJoin is written: "Be aware that if any of the inner observables supplied to forkJoin error you will lose the value of any other observables". but my 2. call is optional.